# Reactively chaining requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm new to reactive programming and stuck at a probably simple point.
I have two methods returning observables.

```
GetQueues(): Observable<Queue[]>{...}
```

and

```
GetMessageCount(queue: Queue): Observable<number>{...}
```

Now I want to chain these in a method with the following signature

```
GetAllQueueMessageCount(): Observable<number>{...}
```

As you can imagine, I want to call the first method to read a list of queues, iterate over the result and call the second one for each of them.

I can imagine something like the following, but as you see, this doesn't return what the signature expects:

```
public GetAllQueueMessageCount(): Observable<number> {
    var messageCount = 0;
    this.GetQueues()
        .subscribe(queues => {
            var queueCountRequests = [];
            queues.forEach((queue) => {
                queueCountRequests.push(this.GetQueueMessageCount(queue));
            });
            Observable.forkJoin(queueCountRequests)
                .subscribe(t => {
                    t.forEach(
                        count => messageCount = messageCount + (count as number));
                });
        }, error => Observable.throw(error));
}
```

All my attempts using flatMap resulted in the same.

Comment: This has been asked a lot of times already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445418/flattening-nested-observables, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255718/combine-multiple-observable-arrays-into-new-object-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the structure you're looking for.

Since you're returning an observable, general rule is use `map()` or a form of it such as `flatMap()` instead of `subscribe()`, and use returns at each level.

```js
const GetAllQueueMessageCount(): Observable<number> {
  return this.GetQueues()
    .map(queues => {
      const queueCountRequests = queues
        .map(queue => this.GetQueueMessageCount(workflowId, queue.Name) );
      return Observable.forkJoin(queueCountRequests)
        .map(
          results: number[] => results.reduce((sum,num) => sum + num, 0))
          error => Observable.throw(error)
         )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two general rules related to your issue:

1. Don't use subscribe manually if you can avoid it, which in your case can most likely be avoided.
2. Avoid client-side-calculations like this, because sending multiple REST-calls (which is assume you are doing) is very heavy on the connection as well as the server and usually takes longer, because there is a limit of how many parallel requests can be done. - So I would strongly suggest to implement a separate endoint for something like this.

That being said, here is how I would write that stream

---

```
public GetAllQueueMessageCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.GetQueues()
        .mergeAll() // split up the array into seperate emissions
        .concatMap(queue => this.GetQueueMessageCount(workflowId, queue.Name))
        .toArray() // optional if you want one single result-emit use it, if you want a new emission for every queueMessageCount, remove it
        .map(msgCounts => msgCounts.reduce((sum,num) => sum + num, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems there's quite an amount of concept I have to read up with. Trying to do as you propose, I encounter the error that the concat method cannot be located.