# How to return observable from subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

For example, I have code like this:

```
// angular service post method
postUser(): Observable<User> {
   this.tokenService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
       // need to return this observable
       return this.http.post<User>(url, {token});
   })
}
```

Comment: what is the problem your are trying to solve by this code ?

Answer (score 2):

If you do this, the return type is `Observable<Observable<User>>`, not nice:

```js
  getUser(): Observable<Observable<User>> {
    return this.accessToken$.pipe(
      map(_ => {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiURL}/user`)
      }),
    );
  }
```

Use `mergeMap`:

```
 getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.accessToken$.pipe(
      mergeMap(_ => {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiURL}/user`)
      }),
    );
  }
```

Refer to "[Flattening nested Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445418/flattening-nested-observables)" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, But you can easily avoid `subscribe` and instead use `map`, or `do`

```
postUser(): Observable<User> {
   return this.tokenService.getToken().map(token => {
       // need to return this observable
       return this.http.post<User>(url, {token});
   })
}
```

you might want to have a look at `mergeMap` and other available operators as well for your use case.
See also https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: Can you do this with HttpClient?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo why do you think that?

Comment: the return type of your snippet is currently `Obsevable<Observable<User>>`

Comment: A fix for the `Observable<Observable<User>>` has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982273/1517394

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of code

```
  save(person: Person) : Observable<Response>{
    return this
      .http
      .put(`${this.baseUrl}/people/${person.id}`,
            JSON.stringify(person),
            {headers: this.getHeaders()});
  }
```

See [here](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/) for more details.

And use [switchMap](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_switchmap.html) to manage nested Observables.

Your post should update the database. Why no user is in parameter of your method ?